# tensorflow.scatter_nd with batches?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use `tf.scatter_nd` for inputs with `locations = (-1, 68, 16, 16, 2)` and `values = (-1, 68, 16, 16)`.

I am having problems using `scatter_nd` with these inputs.

My current workaround is using `tf.map_fn twice`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session():
    BS = 32
    locations = tf.constant(np.clip(np.random.normal(size=(BS, 68, 16, 16, 2))*112, 0, 111), dtype="int32")
    vals = tf.constant(np.random.normal(size=(BS, 68, 16, 16))*20, dtype="float32")
    def draw_lmarks(x):
        def draw_lmarks_inner(x2):
            return tf.scatter_nd(x2[0], x2[1], shape=(IMGSIZE, IMGSIZE))
        return tf.map_fn(draw_lmarks_inner, x, dtype="float32")
    imgs = tf.map_fn(draw_lmarks, [locations, vals], dtype="float32")
    imgs = K.reshape(K.max(imgs, axis=1), [-1, IMGSIZE, IMGSIZE, 1])
```

I'd like to get rid of the two `map_fn` calls.

Is there any alternative that I missed?

**Edit:**
Using `tf.tensor_scatter_update` enables me to get rid of one of the `map_fn` calls, and speed stuff up considerably, but i need the maximum (`tf.tensor_scatter_max`) which doesn't exists.
There is a `tf.scatter_max` tho but somehow i couldn't get that to work like expected.

With tensor_scatter_update; ie. this:

```
img = tf.zeros((112,112), dtype="float32")
def draw_lmarks(x):
    return tf.tensor_scatter_update(img, x[0], x[1])
imgs = tf.map_fn(draw_lmarks, [locations, vals], dtype="float32")
```

i get an output like this
[image]
while i need an output like this
[image]